# How to Animate scrollpoint?

Tags: cocoa, scroll

```
- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSSize dynamicImageSize;
    dynamicImageSize = [[self image] size];
    NSSize contentSize = [(NSScrollView*)[[self superview] superview] contentSize];
    if(dynamicImageSize.height > contentSize.height || dynamicImageSize.width > contentSize.width)
    {
        float x = startOrigin.x - ([theEvent locationInWindow].x - startPt.x);
        float y = startOrigin.y - ([theEvent locationInWindow].y - startPt.y);
        [self scrollPoint:NSMakePoint(x, y)];
    }
}
```

In the above code I need to animate the scrolling. How can I achieve this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how? Seems like a pretty simple request...

Comment: @Chetan: +1, I would like to know this also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my app, I set the `clipView`'s `boundsOrigin` using its animator:

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
NSClipView* clipView = [[myView enclosingScrollView] contentView];
NSPoint newOrigin = [clipView bounds].origin;
newOrigin.x = my_new_origin.x;
[[clipView animator] setBoundsOrigin:newOrigin];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

Comment: I'd be careful with this method - I've seen some weird behaviour (E.g. scrollbars breaking on if the new origin's value isn't an exact integer). From Apple's docs:

**You don't normally interact with the NSClipView class directly; it is provided primarily as the scrolling machinery for the NSScrollView class.**

I be tempted to use Abhi's method which relies on scrollPoint on the document view.

Answer (score 12):

You can create a subclass of `NSAnimation` to do this. I've created one as part of an open source project of mine (with public domain license).

You can find it here: https://github.com/abhibeckert/Dux/blob/master/Dux/DuxScrollViewAnimation.m (note: this project has ARC enabled. If you're not using ARC you will need to update as appropriate).

Example:

```
[DuxScrollViewAnimation animatedScrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(x,y) inScrollView:self.enclosingScrollView];
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. This class is really helpful and the animation works as expected.

Comment: @aumanets keep in mind this should probably be revisited with Mavericks. I haven't done that yet - scroll views don't use cubicEaseInOut anymore. I don't know how to implement the new algorithm.

Comment: Didn't thought about that. Thank you for the warning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a supported animation type, but have you tried calling through the `animator` proxy object?

eg. `[[self animator] scrollPoint:NSMakePoint(x, y)];`

Comment: Nope, that won't work. That's not a supported animatable property (although perhaps it would be a good enhancement request?).